# How to copy a file from a Sharepoint where I'm not site owner?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, power-automate, rpa

I'm trying to get a csv file from a Sharepoint where is updated every day. Unfortunately there is no way to upgrade my access to owner. There is a work around to get the file automatically without this permissions level by using Power Automate or Logic Apps from Azure? I've been trying and both of them throws me the error described down below when I'm configuring the workflow:

Logic Apps:
[image]

Power Automate:
[image]

Comment: For information security reasons, permissions should be required.